# MVC NET 5 linked model saves to database but doesn't load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm fairly new to .NET MVC 5, coming from a primarily PHP background.  I have a 'Project' model with a List collection in it.  When I use just a test controller to save data into the collection, it will save into the database just fine.

The problem arises when I'm trying to pull information out of that collection, as it always comes back as null.

My Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project")]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public string Client { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }

    public string ProjectManagerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectManagerId")]
    [Display(Name = "Project Manager")]
    public ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Members")]
    public int[] ProjectMembers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tasks")]
    public List<ProjectTask> TaskCollection { get; set; }

}

public class ProjectDb : DbContext
{
    public ProjectDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

My ProjectTask model:
    public class ProjectTask
    {

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string TaskNotes { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } 

    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }

    public TaskAlertLevel AlertLevel { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectTask> SubTasks { get; set; }

    public string Progress { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectTaskDb : DbContext
{
    public ProjectTaskDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Project> ProjectTasks { get; set; }
}
```

My controller where I'm just trying to see something other than null exceptions:

```
public ActionResult DetailTasks(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var tasks = project.TaskCollection;

        ViewBag.tasks = tasks;
        return View(project);

    }
```

Hopefully it's something completely obvious and stupid that escapes me right now!

Comment: Are you sure you are actually saving it to the DB? If you are calling db.Projects.Add(whatever); and not calling db.SaveChanges(); after that then it never actually gets saved to your database in the first place, it just does a soft add but doesn't commit changes.

Comment: Yup it's definitely saving, as I'm calling db.Projects.Add(project) as well as db.SaveChanges().  The test data shows up in the raw database tables too, they just never come out to visit.

Comment: May be best to check if your ID column is actually marked as the primary key and if not then put the [Key] Data attribute above it and add new migration/update database. 

If it is still acting wonkly then you can always flip the line to 
Project project = db.Projects.where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Nope no good, it will pull the data from the Project model just fine, but Project.TaskCollection always comes back null.  I've tried so many different permutations it's driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies in regards to the comments,  for some reason I thought you were having issues loading up the initial project object. So looking at your Project entities you have lazy loading turned off because you are not using the virtual keyword:

```
public List<ProjectTask> TaskCollection { get; set; }
```

vs

```
public virtual List<ProjectTask> TaskCollection { get; set; }
```

When you do this you must either Explicitly or Eagerly load your TaskCollection

Exlicitly load:

```
Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
db.Entry(project).List(a => a.TaskCollection).Load();
```

Eagerly Load:

```
Project project = db.Projects.where(a => a.ID == id).Include(b => b.TaskCollection).FirstOrDefault();
```

p.s. you may have to play with my context a bit as I'm not at a place where I can load-up VS

Comment: I added virtual to the TaskCollection and it started loading data, I'm thinking I just have no idea when to use virtual or not in this type of framework.  Now back to figuring out some weird circular reference errors, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear, here is a pretty good break down of the when and why if your brain needs a break from fighting circular references: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/11/01/lazy-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with changing this line: `var tasks = project.TaskCollection;` to like this: `var tasks = project.TaskCollection.ToList();`, it may help you

Full example/Changed Code:

```
public ActionResult DetailTasks(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var tasks = project.TaskCollection.ToList();

        ViewBag.tasks = tasks;
        return View(project);

    }
```

I believe this time you wont get null for the project.TaskCollection , if the data available in the database.

Hope the above the information was useful , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I tried that, and it's still giving me a null result.

The table for ProjectTask has data in it, I've pulled it up and checked multiple times, and the data should be linked to the project properly as if I try to delete the project line in the database it throws referential integrity errors.